# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I'm trying to run a very basic Eureka Server but it gives the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'eurekaServerBootstrap'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaServerBootstrap' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/server/EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'eurekaServerBootstrap' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'peerAwareInstanceRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/server/EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.eureka.registry.PeerAwareInstanceRegistry]: Factory method 'peerAwareInstanceRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient]: Factory method 'eurekaClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1415) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:608) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at com.microservices.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaServerBootstrap' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/server/EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'eurekaServerBootstrap' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'peerAwareInstanceRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/server/EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.eureka.registry.PeerAwareInstanceRegistry]: Factory method 'peerAwareInstanceRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient]: Factory method 'eurekaClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:539) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1367) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'peerAwareInstanceRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/server/EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.eureka.registry.PeerAwareInstanceRegistry]: Factory method 'peerAwareInstanceRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient]: Factory method 'eurekaClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1367) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.eureka.registry.PeerAwareInstanceRegistry]: Factory method 'peerAwareInstanceRegistry' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient]: Factory method 'eurekaClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient]: Factory method 'eurekaClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:381) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.0-M6.jar:3.0.0-M6]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:184) ~[spring-cloud-context-3.0.0-M6.jar:3.0.0-M6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:371) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:195) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy70.getApplications(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.peerAwareInstanceRegistry(EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.java:148) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server-3.0.0-M6.jar:3.0.0-M6]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient]: Factory method 'eurekaClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:436) ~[eureka-client-1.10.10.jar:1.10.10]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:283) ~[eureka-client-1.10.10.jar:1.10.10]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:279) ~[eureka-client-1.10.10.jar:1.10.10]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:66) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.0.0-M6.jar:3.0.0-M6]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:292) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-3.0.0-M6.jar:3.0.0-M6]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/client/apache4/ApacheHttpClient4
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.Jersey1TransportClientFactories.newTransportClientFactory(Jersey1TransportClientFactories.java:59) ~[eureka-client-1.10.10.jar:1.10.10]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.scheduleServerEndpointTask(DiscoveryClient.java:528) ~[eureka-client-1.10.10.jar:1.10.10]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:423) ~[eureka-client-1.10.10.jar:1.10.10]
    ... 77 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 80 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried debugging around the `pom.xml` file, and ended up adding some dependencies, but nothing seem to change!

Here is the `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.microservices</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Bootmicroservices Microservices</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0-M6</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

And here is my very simple `main`

```
package com.microservices.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Added the dependency mentioned below & perform `mvn clean install` and try again

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: this worked for me, but why this dependency require and missed in spring boot? i worked with the other microservice project that not have any error!

Comment: This was an issue with Spring boot older versions. Check the link mentioned below which will give you exact information about this bug.                           https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/3953

Comment: @amirazizkhani be careful please! ;)

Answer (score 6):

```
Add the below dependencies in the pom.xml along with the other required dependencies. It will work fine.

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

Add Dependency in pom.xml and resolve it

Actually i am facing same issues when developing micro-services structure

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

Either of below can be used solve the issue

Remove below dependency if you are using it as a server.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

OR

Add below dependency

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue, and also tried all above methods, none of those worked for me.

finally I observed, my **STS version was 4.0**, so guys if you are using STS 4.0 or higher, you will face this issue again and again.

kindly use STS **version- 3.9.11** or any other STS version 3. Do not use version 2 and 4. there is a compatibility issue for Netflix Eureka with STS version 4.0 and higher.

Download link for STS 3.9.11 is --> https://github.com/spring-projects/toolsuite-distribution/wiki/Spring-Tool-Suite-3

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok, resolved, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, but figure out just add the wrong eureka server dependency, the correct one should include "starter".

```
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-**starter**-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
<version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the error!

It's in the spring cloud version of **eureka** of **server-config** and **zull** (in case you are using), all must be between **Hoxton.SR10**, **Hoxton.SR11** or **Hoxton.SR12**.

Yes, I tested them all

Answer (score 1):

My Err is:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'eurekaServerBootstrap'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaServerBootstrap' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/server/EurekaServerAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'eurekaServerBootstrap' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eurekaServerContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
```

My solution is to remove the devtool dependency in pom, to disable live reload when run as services
[https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-boot-devtools#:~:text=DevTools%20stands%20for%20Developer%20Tool,changes%20and%20restart%20the%20application](https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-boot-devtools#:%7E:text=DevTools%20stands%20for%20Developer%20Tool,changes%20and%20restart%20the%20application).

Comment: Please only use a code snippet for code written in HTML, CSS or JavaScript. Otherwise, a snippet won't work and is just distracting. Use regular markdown to format your posts, see [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

I've also faced the same issue recently.
In my case, I had to maintain the following steps.

1. **eureka.client.enabled=false** // remove this line from application.properties file.
2. **set the server.port=8761** // **port exactly to 8761**; I've tried with port **8080**, which leads to an exception on application startup
3. Added  jersey dependency mentioned by @Akshay Jain

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.4</version>
</dependency>
```

4. Set spring cloud version to **2020.0.0**

```
    <properties>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this solved my case:

I update verison of the `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` from `3.1.3` to `3.1.4`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and in my pom.xml
I changed to <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.2</spring-cloud.version> and it worked without errors.`<spring-cloud.version>2021.0.2</spring-cloud.version>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-apache-client4</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this dependency from client side

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

- also you might face this issue in spring boot version 3X

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Finally I resolve this

added annotation at the top of main class",

"add annotation at the top of main class",

```
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServiceRegistryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceRegistryApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```